# Asio standalone thread_pool.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using the standalone version of Asio from [here](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio). Does anyone know how to post/dispatch a function onto the threadpool object in thread_pool.hpp? It looks to me that this is implemented as a method of the executor type (?) but calling get_executor().post(function) on a thread_pool object yields compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the standalone post? it works for me with boost::asio.

```
boost::asio::thread_pool pool(4u);

for (auto i = 0u; i < 4u; i++)
{
    boost::asio::post(pool, []() {std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); });
}

pool.join();
```